# Missing of image when conversion from flv to 3gp

Tags: ffmpeg, video-encoding, 3gp

I use in command line for ffmpeg

```
-i Input.flv -vcodec h263 -b 256k -r 15 -s 320x240 -acodec libopencore_amrnb \
-ab 7.4k -ar 8000 -ac 1 -f 3gp Output.3gp
```

The result is audio-only, without video. But when the  176x144, it works great.

**What's wrong in using of frame size (320x240)?  And what is the solution?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure there is no video in the resulting Output.3gp file?  Is it possible that the end device does not support 320x240?

It would help significantly if you were to include the *entire* FFmpeg output in your question.

Comment: Right! H.263 support only: 128x96, 176x144, 352x288, 704x576 and 1408x1152.